# C# Generics List of List

Tags: c#, list, generics

Hi I have a simple issue with an sql application that I seem not to be capable of resolve. It involves the use of generics of which I am not too familiar with. I did researches here and on-line but I do not seem to find a fitting solution for my case.

I have two classes: Table and Field. I want Table to contain a List of Field and I want each Field to contain a List of RecordSet. The tricky part is that I want the user to choose which type of RecordSet to implement.

The Class Definition of Table is:

```
namespace DBlib
{
    public class DBTable<T>
    {
        public List<DBField<T>> FieldName = new List<DBField<T>>();

        public DBTable (string NameOfTable)
        {
        }

        public void AddField (string Name)
        {
            DBField<T> TempList = new DBField<T>();
            FieldName.Add(TempList);
        }
    }
}
```

The Class Definition of Field is:

```
namespace DBlib
{
    public class DBField<T>
    {
        public List<T> RecordSet = new List<T>();

        public DBField()
        {            
        }         
    }
}
```

With this code the user is forced cast the  type when he is instantiating DBTable. This is not correct. I want the user to cast the  type when the AddField method is invoked. Can you suggest a simple way to solve this issue?

UPDATE #1
I changed TempList as DBField in the Table Class definition. Sorry for the confusion there.

I want to add also this code to explain better what my issue is. Assuming the first Field of the table is an integer, the user should do:

```
namespace SpecifytheName
{
    public class User
    {
        DBTable<int> Table = new DBTable<int>(); 

        public User()
        {            
        }         
    }
}
```

Instead, I want the user to do:

```
namespace SpecifytheName
{
    public class User
    {
        DBTable Table1 = new DBTable("Table1"); 

        // SPECIFY THE TYPE OF FIELD1 ONLY AT THIS POINT
        Table1.AddField<int>("Field1");  //or something like this

        public User()
        {            
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "casting" are you referring to specifying the type? Because simply put that's just how C# works. When you create a generic class you need to specify the type when the instance of the class is created. To me it sounds like you're trying to change the behavior of the language itself.

Comment: `TempList` would have to be of type `List<DBField<T>>` for the above to work anyway wouldn't it

Comment: I'm sorry but your edit changes nothing. If you want a generic class rather than a normal class that contains a generic list you have to follow the rules of the language.

Comment: So `DBField` is actually going to be a column?

Comment: @m.t.bennett That is exactly the intent...

Comment: But how exactly is the user supposed to specify (at runtime?) that the type is to be "int" (or "double" or whatever?)

Comment: What I think is most important at this point, without knowing any more detail about what you're actually trying to do, is why you aren't using the standard data types associated with working with SQL?

Comment: He does seem to be trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: I know nothing about "dynamic languages", but is that perhaps what he needs, without knowing it? Iron Python?

Comment: @LuckyLuke What we're attempting to find out from you is A) What part of generics you are actually struggling with B) If you aren't making a simple task more difficult than it should be and C) What it is you actually hope to accomplish with this code.

Comment: The thing you need to grasp about C# generics is that the part of the program coded for generic types (class or method) does not need to know the type at compile-time (I'm over-simplifying here). BUT somewhere at compile-time, the part of the program that USES these classes or methods DOES need to specify the type. It is not something that can be pulled out of the air at runtime.

Comment: C# generics are very powerful and I love them, but they do not implement mind-reading. :-)

Comment: @RenniePet Thank. I got that. Infact the classes Table and Field are under the namespace DBlib which belongs to my dll. The user Class is in a different project. All I wanted was a way for the user class to specify the type in the Field instance rather than the Table instance. If you look my code above it should appear what I am referring to. Thanks!

Comment: @LuckyLuke from your last comment it sounds like Enigmativity's answer should be very similar to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally solve this issue using a non-generic interface to store your fields.

So start with this interface:

```
public interface IDBField
{
    IList RecordSet { get; }
    Type FieldType { get; }
}
```

Now implement `DBField<T>` like this:

```
public class DBField<T> : IDBField
{
    public List<T> RecordSet = new List<T>();

    IList IDBField.RecordSet
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RecordSet;
        }
    }

    Type IDBField.FieldType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }      
}
```

Then you can implement `DBTable` like this:

```
public class DBTable
{
    public List<IDBField> FieldName = new List<IDBField>();

    public void AddField<F>(string Name)
    {
        FieldName.Add(new DBField<F>());
    }
}
```

You can use the `FieldType` property on `IDBField` to determine the type of the field and then use reflection as necessary to use the values of `RecordSet` appropriately.

Comment: Isn't there something missing about how the field name gets used?

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi Thank you. this is exactly what i was looking for and I vote this as the answer that solves the problem. Thanks Again!

Comment: @RenniePet - Yes, there is, but that was missing in the question too so I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is by not using Generics, but just use the `Object` class.

for example:

```
public class DBTable
{
    public List<DBField<Object>> FieldName = new List<DBField<Object>>();

    public DBTable (string NameOfTable)
    {
    }

    public void AddField(string Name)
    {
        List<DBField<Object>> TempList = new List<DBField<Object>>();
        FieldName.Add(TempList);
    }
}
```

This will mean you can use any type in the `RecordSet` object without restricting the type in the DBTable class.

I could be a bit off base here as I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, for one you aren't going anything with the `Name` parameter passed into the `AddField` method, and you're `TempList` object isn't the same type as `FieldName` so it should throw some errors there..

EDIT:

I think I understand more clearly what you're trying to do, try this -

```
public class DBTable
{
    public List<DBField<Object>> FieldName = new List<DBField<Object>>();

    public DBTable (string NameOfTable)
    {
    }

    public void AddField<FieldType>(string Name)
    {
        DBField<FieldType> field = new DBField<FieldType>(Name);
        FieldName.Add(field);
    }
}
```

This way each Field (Column) is still forced to a type, but the DBTable isn't tied down to that same type.

Comment: In this case it would probably just be simpler to use a jagged array rather than to still create `DBField` as a generic with type `Object`

Comment: I understand what you're trying to accomplish with your answer but I don't believe the OP has a clear understanding of generics and how they work and function in C#.

Comment: He mentioned that in his post. I think more specifically we need to know what he's trying to achieve, regardless of his Generics use.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Yes I don't have a clear picture of how generics work yet. I reading and coding (and making mistakes) trying to learn them. In general I am trying to build a simple custom Library that deals with a Database. I want the library to provide the user an object called Table and an object called Field. In the object Field i will have a recordSet that can be cleared and used to save data after a SELECT statement or to collect the data for an INSERT or UPDATE. Something simple to get my feet wet.Thank you for your help!

Comment: @LuckyLuke Then you are indeed trying to reinvent the wheel. Great libraries for working with SQL already exist. If you wish to learn how to properly use generics you should start with something a little simpler.